# Messed up my $PATH variable

Tags: shell

When I was trying to install golang I ran the command export `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`. Now whenever I try to run a command like clear it says "cannot find path". When I do echo path I get `/snap/bin /usr/local/go/bin`.
How can I fix this and get my Path back to normal.
I am using Pop OS 20.04.

Comment: export on a command line only changes the variable for the current shell instance.  Did you try logging out and logging in again?

Comment: No I have not let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You can find a default PATH setting this way:

```
$ cat /etc/login.defs | grep ENV_PATH
ENV_PATH    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```